# How to replace Python list item by multiple items?

Tags: python

```
input_list = [[0], 'h1'] # contain an arbitrary number of 'h1' in arbitrary indices
input_keys = {'h1':[[1],[1]]} # all key values are lists
# to implement
replace(input_list, input_keys) -> [[0], [1],[1] ]
```

How to replace element `'h1'` from `input_list` by multiple elements from `input_keys['h1']`?

I have tried:

```
#[[0], [1, 1]]
list(map(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, str) else list(itertools.chain(*input_keys[x])), input_list))
    
#[[0], [[1], [1]]]
list(map(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, str) else input_keys[x], input_list))
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: is `input_list` going to contain an arbitrary number of `'h1'` in arbitrary indices? Do you care about *other* keys in `input_keys`? If so, what would those values look like?

Comment: The result you have shown is somewhat confusing. Didn't you want to have `[[0], [[1],[1]]]` instead?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani no, I want to have `[[0],  [1],[1]  ]` I have fixed typo. Sorry.

Comment: `[b for a in input_list for b in input_key.get(a, (a,))]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop will do the job.

```py
output_list = []
for item in input_list:
   if str(item) in input_keys:
       output_list.extend(input_keys[item])
   else:
       output_list.append(item)
```

Note that I'm converting lists in the `input_list` into strings in order to check that they're in the dictionary of `input_keys`.

Comment: This doesn't get the output the OP wants, you'd want `output_list.extend(input_keys[item])`. Also, just use `in input_keys` no need for `in input_keys.keys()`

Comment: Well spotted, thanks ‍

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

for index, item in enumerate(item_list):
    if isinstance(item, collections.Hashable) and item in input_keys:
        item_list[index] = input_keys[item]
```

Comment: You are right. I missed that nested list. Updated the answer so that is works now.

Answer (score 0):

One solution looks like this

```
def replace(listin, keysin):
    
    for key, val in keysin.items():
        key_idx = listin.index(key)
        listin.pop(key_idx)
        for v in val[::-1]:
            listin.insert(key_idx, v)
    
    return listin

listin = [[0], 'h1']
keysin = {'h1': [[1],[1]]}

print(replace(listin, keysin))
>> [[0], [1], [1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using yield:

```
def replace_generator(input_list, input_keys):
  for x in input_list:
    if not isinstance(x, str):
      yield x
    else:
      if x in input_keys:
        for y in input_keys[x]:
          yield y

list(replace_generator(input_list, input_keys))
>> [[0], [1], [1]]
```